# Optimizing function call from for loop

Tags: c++, function, optimization, for-loop

I have some simple functions

```
int f_0(int);
int f_1(int);
...
int f_n(int);
```

and then I have some for loops in which I call f_i(), the condition in this loops doesnt have to be the same

```
for (int i = 0; i < n; i++) {
   ...
   if (condition) {
      int myInt = f_i(); // this is not real implementation but shows the result
                         // I want to achieve
      ... //edit
   }
...
}
```

Here are the ways I tried to implement this:

- Breaking down the for loop and calling each function in correspondning part. This results in fastest code but this is higly unelegant and such code is hard to be further developed.
- Pointers to functions

  `typedef int (*Foo) (int);`

  `Foo fptr[] = { f_0, f_1, ... , f_n };`

this is elegant method but in my case it is 4.4 slower than breaking down the loop. Constant pointers to functions yield simmilar results.

- Encapsulating my functions into switch function. This was 2.6 slower than breaking down the loop.

Is there any better way how to implement this? **Ideal solution would be the one with compact code but the compiler would break down the loop and let the calculations be the fastest.**

I´m using MSVC 2012 and running on release mode with optimizations set to maximize speed.

**Edit:**

Here is my testing code:

head.h

```
namespace c {
const int w = 1024;
const int A = w * w;
}

inline int f_0(int pos)  { return (pos - c::w + c::A) % c::A;           }
inline int f_1(int pos)  { return (pos + 1 - c::w + c::A) % c::A;       }
inline int f_2(int pos)  { return (pos + 1) % c::A;                     }
inline int f_3(int pos)  { return (pos + c::w) % c::A;                  }
inline int f_4(int pos)  { return (pos - 1 + c::w) % c::A;              }
inline int f_5(int pos)  { return (pos - 1 + c::A) % c::A;              }

typedef int (*NEIGH_F) (int);
typedef int (* const CNEIGH_F) (int);

const NEIGH_F  fptr[]  = { f_0, f_1, f_2, f_3, f_4, f_5 };
const CNEIGH_F cfptr[] = { f_0, f_1, f_2, f_3, f_4, f_5 };

inline int fswitch(int i, int pos) {
    switch(i) {
    case 0 : return f_0(pos); break;
    case 1 : return f_1(pos); break;
    case 2 : return f_2(pos); break;
    case 3 : return f_3(pos); break;
    case 4 : return f_4(pos); break;
    case 5 : return f_5(pos); break;
    default : return -1; break;
    }
}
```

main.cpp

```
#include "head.h"
#include <iostream>
#include <time.h>

int main()
{
    int maxRepeat = 100;

    clock_t startTime = clock();
    double sum = 0;
    for (int repeat = 0; repeat < maxRepeat; repeat++)
        for (int i = 0; i < c::A; i++) {
            sum += f_0(i);
            sum += f_1(i);
            sum += f_2(i);
            sum += f_3(i);
            sum += f_4(i);
            sum += f_5(i);
        }
    std::cout << "normal time:        " << (clock() - startTime)/(double)CLOCKS_PER_SEC
                 << "  sum is: " << sum << std::endl;

    startTime = clock();
    sum = 0;
    for (int repeat = 0; repeat < maxRepeat; repeat++)
        for (int i = 0; i < c::A; i++) {
            for (int j = 0; j < 6; j++)
                sum += fptr[j](i);
        }
    std::cout << "pointer time:       " << (clock() - startTime)/(double)CLOCKS_PER_SEC
                 << "  sum is: " << sum << std::endl;

    startTime = clock();
    sum = 0;
    for (int repeat = 0; repeat < maxRepeat; repeat++)
        for (int i = 0; i < c::A; i++) {
            for (int j = 0; j < 6; j++)
                sum += cfptr[j](i);
        }
    std::cout << "const pointer time: " << (clock() - startTime)/(double)CLOCKS_PER_SEC
                 << "  sum is: " << sum << std::endl;

    startTime = clock();
    sum = 0;
    for (int repeat = 0; repeat < maxRepeat; repeat++)
        for (int i = 0; i < c::A; i++) {
            for (int j = 0; j < 6; j++)
                sum += fswitch(j, i);
        }
    std::cout << "switch time:        " << (clock() - startTime)/(double)CLOCKS_PER_SEC
                 << "  sum is: " << sum << std::endl;
    std::cin.ignore();

    return 0;
}
```

functions f_i are the functions I use in my real implementation, but the loops here are much simpler due to testing purposes in real implementation there are several different loops of form shown in second code snippet in the question.

**Edit2:**

The form of my loop should stay the same I just want to find the best way how to put f_i into my loops.

Comment: Can we see the code for each of your solutions? i.e. Breaking down for loop, pointer array, switch. **EDIT:** Also, your code smells. Why do you have functions `f_0,f_1,...f_n`?? You would be served much better by simply writing code which logically achieves what you are trying to do in the simplest code possible. **EDIT EDIT:** Also, why is performance so critical that you can't spare 4.4 units? Unless it's days or something.

Comment: What does condition depend on? If condition is unpredictable then you will suffer branch misprediction penalties even with the version where you call the functions directly. You'd likely get better performance if you can arrange to move the conditions outside of the loop. For example, if the condition depended on some data in an array you would likely see better performance by sorting the array according to the condition.

Comment: @Andrew Dunn i´ll update my post and add my implementations tommorow EDIT: the functions are there becuase they are crucial to next lines of loop nad it has to be done for output of all f_i() if condition is met fo i EDIT EDIT: this code is for kinetic monet carlo simulation which where speed is really crucial


@ mattnewport the condition is unpredictable and cannot be put anywhere else

Comment: What is a realistic value of N? Is it known at compile time?

Comment: The conditions are not mutually exclusive right? You may need to call multiple different f_i()? How expensive are the f_i()? Sometimes for small amounts of work it is cheaper to just do the work unconditionally rather than take an unpredictable branch to try and avoid doing work. Are the conditions completely independent or are some combinations of f_i() mutually exclusive?

Comment: you can try template function. change `f_i()` to `f<I>()`

Comment: @NicholasM N < 10 and is known at compile time

Comment: @mattnewport the functions are just a couple of additions and modulos but with condition it is still faster because it is simply checked condition

Comment: @BryanChen I don´t know much about templates could you show how would I implement this?

Comment: If the functions are simple and marked inline and they are not inside a condition I would expect the compiler to inline them and save the cost of the conditional branch and function call. They are probably getting inlined anyway in your version that does direct calls and the conditional is predictable enough that avoiding the work is a performance win if you've measured without the conditional and found it is slower though.

Comment: @mattnewport i use inlined function but they are in condition and there is more stuff in this condition too now i use the switch version of calling the right function and its surely not the best way this can be done

Comment: You still have not really answered whether the functions are mututally exclusive.  Can you just post the ideal psuedocode for the case where `N` is 3?  Is it `if (cond1) f1();  if (cond2) f2(); if (cond3) f3()`?

What are cond1, cond2, and cond3 functions _of_?  Some loop index?  Some external state?  We could come up with some slick compile-time loops using recursive templates, if only we understood the problem we were trying to solve.

Comment: @NicholasM functions are mutually exclusive condition is dependent on loop index and it is an external state too

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Are the `f_i()` functions and the `A` and `w` constants truly those given? Because if they are, isn't this problem trivially reducible to a table lookup, an addition and a bitwise AND?

```
/* Includes */
#include <stdio.h>
#include <time.h>


/* Constants */
const int w = 1024;
const int A = 1024*1024;
const int addconst[6] = {0xFFC00, 0xFFC01, 0x00001, 0x00400, 0x003FF, 0xFFFFF};
                      /*     A-w,   A-w+1,       1,       w,     w-1,     A-1 */

/* THE NOVELTY */
int ftable(int i, int pos){
    return (pos + addconst[i]) & 0xFFFFF;
}

/* Main */
int main(int argc, char* argv[]){
    clock_t timeTaken;
    int     repeat, maxRepeat = 100;
    int     i, j;
    long    sum = 0;

    timeTaken  = -clock();
    for(repeat=0;repeat<maxRepeat;repeat++)
        for(i=0;i<A;i++)
            for(j=0;j<6;j++)
                sum += ftable(j, i);
    timeTaken += clock();

    printf("Stop! Hammertime!        %f  sum is: %f\n",
           timeTaken/(double)CLOCKS_PER_SEC, (double)sum);
    return 0;
}
```

Please note that when the `sum` variable is a `long`, the time taken is:

```
Stop! Hammertime!        0.348295  sum is: 329853173760000.000000
```

while when it is a `double`, it takes more than twice as long:

```
Stop! Hammertime!        0.861563  sum is: 329853173760000.000000
```

My compile flags are:

```
gcc -O3 -funroll-loops -finline-functions tmp.c -o tmp
```

If you could explain some more how the function index depends on the loop index, I could optimize some more.

Comment: A and w are compile known constants yes.
Breaking down the code and writing in incomprehensible symbols is unecessary as is using bitwise and those tasks I leave to compiler hence in those cases he knows the best ways how to optimize that.
However your lookup table seems to be the perfect solution here, thanks a lot.
function index is effectively just random int from [0, A) so i dont think there are further optimizations at hand.

Answer (score 4):

you can use template function instead of `f_0`, `f_1`... nicer to maintain.

```
template <int N>
void f();

template <>
void f<0>()
{
    printf("f<0>");
}

template <>
void f<1>()
{
    printf("f<1>");
}

int main() {
    f<0>();
    f<1>();
    //f<2>(); // this is compile error
    return 0;
}
```

however, the template argument must be provided as compile-time constant, so you can't call function like `int i = 0; f<i>()`

to workaround this, you can use switch-case to call function, not very pretty, but works

```
void call_f(int i)
{
    switch(i)
    {
        case 0:
            f<0>();
            break;
        case 1:
            f<1>();
            break;
        default:
            // invalid i, report error
            break;
    }
}
```

however, there is no compile-time check to `i`

[put all together](http://ideone.com/PE1KY1)

Comment: your template + switch solution is slightly slower than my pure switch solution (check edit to my question)

Answer (score 2):

I think Bryan Chen's template-based solution makes a lot of sense.  It would be easier to maintain and understand.  I upvoted that solution.

That said, if you wanted a more general solution without a switch statement, and you wanted to test all conditions in an "unrolled" way, you could use compile-time recursion with templates.

I did it with 3 functions, based on *Condition* functors that take a single integer argument.  Obviously, you could make the conditions simpler, or more complicated, according to your needs.

The core of this involves a template defintion that is recursive, plus a template specialization to stop the recursion:

```
template <int N>
struct Condition;  // provides bool operator()(int arg)

template <int N>
void f();

template <int N>
void applyFunctions(int arg);

// Specialization placed first for clarity
template <>
void applyFunctions<0>(int arg)
{
  if (Condition<0>()(arg))
  {
    f<0>();
  }
  // End recursion
};

template <int N>
void applyFunctions(int arg)
{
  if (Condition<N>()(arg))
  {
    f<N>();
  }

  applyFunctions<N - 1>(arg);
};
```

Here is some output.  The phrases are printed in the condition checks, while the `[f<i>]` are printed within the function calls.  I aligned the printed output for clarity.

```
Loop
j = 0:                       Is even. [f<1>]       Always true. [f<0>]
j = 1:                                             Always true. [f<0>]
j = 2:  Is prime. [f<2>]     Is even. [f<1>]       Always true. [f<0>]
j = 3:  Is prime. [f<2>]                           Always true. [f<0>]
j = 4:                       Is even. [f<1>]       Always true. [f<0>]
j = 5:  Is prime. [f<2>]                           Always true. [f<0>]
j = 6:                       Is even. [f<1>]       Always true. [f<0>]
j = 7:  Is prime. [f<2>]                           Always true. [f<0>]
j = 8:                       Is even. [f<1>]       Always true. [f<0>]
j = 9:                                             Always true. [f<0>]
j = 10:                      Is even. [f<1>]       Always true. [f<0>]
```

The full program is below.  If you really wanted to do something cool, you could make the `Condition` struct have a member variable that is calculated in a `constexpr` way, so that the inclusion of the resulting code is determined at compile time.  If that doesn't mean anything to you, you would probably want to read up on templates, template instantiation, and metaprogramming.

```
#include <iostream>
#include <iomanip>

static int fw = 20;

template <int N>
struct Condition;

template <int N>
void f();


// Specialization 0
template <>
struct Condition<0>
{
  bool operator() (int arg)
  {
    std::cout << std::setw(fw) << " Always true. ";
    return true;
  }
};

template <>
void f<0>()
{
  std::cout << "[f<0>]";
}

// Specialization 1
template <>
struct Condition<1>
{
  bool operator() (int arg)
  {
    bool isEven = (arg % 2 == 0);
    if (isEven)
      std::cout << std::setw(fw) << " Is even. ";
    else 
      std::cout << std::setw(fw) << " ";
    return isEven;
  }
};

template <>
void f<1>()
{
  std::cout << "[f<1>]";
}


// Specialization 2
template <>
struct Condition<2>
{
  bool operator() (int arg)
  {
    bool isPrime = (arg == 2 || arg == 3 || arg == 5 || arg == 7);
    if (isPrime)
      std::cout << std::setw(fw) << " Is prime. ";
    else 
      std::cout << std::setw(fw) << " ";
    return isPrime;
  }
};

template <>
void f<2>()
{
  std::cout<< "[f<2>]";
}


template <int N>
void applyFunctions(int arg);

template <>
void applyFunctions<0>(int arg)
{
  if (Condition<0>()(arg))
  {
    f<0>();
  }
  // End recursion
};

template <int N>
void applyFunctions(int arg)
{
  if (Condition<N>()(arg))
  {
    f<N>();
  }

  applyFunctions<N - 1>(arg);
};


int main()
{
  applyFunctions<2>(4);

  std::cout << std::endl << "Loop" << std::endl;
  for (int j = 0; j < 11; ++j)
  {
    std::cout << "j = " << j << ": ";
    applyFunctions<2>(j);
    std::cout << std::endl;
  }
}
```

Comment: thanks for help, but the thing is there are more for loops which use f_i() and the conditions dont have to be the same in all those loops

Comment: You could reuse the `f<N>` functions and the idea, but have a different set of tests for the other conditions (e.g. struct template called `SecondCondition`).  You could even template the `applyFunctions` struct on the condition's _template_ name by using a so-called _template template_ parameter.

Comment: Also, after I posted my answer, you commented that the conditions are mutually exclusive.  Accordingly, you could `return` within `applyFunctions` if a single condition is met.

Comment: thanks for your help but there is too much such conditions and they are unpredictable so this wouldn´t result in very maintainable code

Answer (score 2):

The following two tweaks radically change the output of results from your program (thanks for the clean compiling code!). These demonstrate that performance optimization has a clear trade-off between build-time vs. run-time uncertainty: you can write more optimal code if you know what function you will be calling, or what target machine you will be running on.

Function call through a pointer gives you the flexibility to call a function at run-time at the cost of not inlining the function calls. Modifying calls to the following makes pointer time equal to normal time.

```
normal time:        1.36  sum is: 3.29853e+14
pointer time:       1.36  sum is: 3.29853e+14
const pointer time: 1.35  sum is: 3.29853e+14
switch time:        1.14  sum is: 3.29853e+14
```

Changes were unrolling the function call in the loop, thus:

```
   sum += fptr[1](i);
   sum += fptr[2](i);
   sum += fptr[3](i);
   sum += fptr[4](i);
   sum += fptr[5](i);
```

`fswitch()` is faster than normal for the case you showed perhaps because inlining inside `fswitch()` creates a set of instructions that get cached. Maybe someone with the requisite expertise could demonstrate this with disassembly of the generated executable. For my test, I enlarged the switch function a bit (by double `switch` branches by duplicating them as shown below), and found that it runs roughly 4 times slower than normal:

```
normal time:        2.35  sum is: 6.59706e+14
pointer time:       2.35  sum is: 6.59706e+14
const pointer time: 2.34  sum is: 6.59706e+14
switch time:        9.61  sum is: 6.59706e+14
```

The changes were:

```
case 6 : return f_0(pos); break;
case 7 : return f_1(pos); break;
case 8 : return f_2(pos); break;
case 9 : return f_3(pos); break;
case 10 : return f_4(pos); break;
case 11 : return f_5(pos); break;
```

...

```
for (int j = 0; j < 12; j++)
    sum += fswitch(j, i);
```

...

```
const NEIGH_F  fptr[]  = { f_0, f_1, f_2, f_3, f_4, f_5, f_0, f_1, f_2, f_3, f_4, f_5 };
const CNEIGH_F cfptr[] = { f_0, f_1, f_2, f_3, f_4, f_5, f_0, f_1, f_2, f_3, f_4, f_5 };
```

...

```
for (int j = 0; j < 12; j++)
    sum += fptr[j](i);
```

...

etc.

Comment: But in my implementation I cannot unrol the functions becasue loops are more complicated there. How didi you accomplish that switch is faster than normal? On my pc switch runs 2,5 longer than normal

Comment: `fswitch` was faster than normal as-is in your code on my box: `normal/pointer/const pointer/switch` are `1.36, 5.31, 3.41, 1.14`. With `long double sum` (instead of `double sum`), the timings change to `1.16, 4.36, 7.46, 1.16` respectively. Unless somebody can elucidate what all butterflies flapping wings can impact compiler optimizations, the best bet is to write maintainable code with no obvious algorithmic or code pessimizations -- that guarantees you at least one virtue of clean code. Of course, this being `stackoverflow`, I would like for some expert to provide definitive perf guidance.

Comment: what compiler do you use? and what flags do you have turned on? However in my real application the switch solution probably wont be optimized iven with your compiler.

Comment: g++ -Wall -O3 -pedantic -std=c++11 -I/usr/include    trypointer0.cc   -o trypointer0
g++ (Ubuntu/Linaro 4.8.1-10ubuntu8) 4.8.1
The spirit of my answer was that compiler optimizations to `switch` may or may not benefit you depending upon your CPU cache size and number of cases.

Comment: I just found out that O3 option uses the flag -funswitch-loops which is probably doing the trick.